# Getting value of array object in Twig file Symfony

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, twig

I have following set of an array that is pass to twig file.

```
others ={
          0:{id : 10, name: krist},
          1:{id : 20,  name: ryan}
         }
```

When I retrieve back from twig file, I retrieve as follow.

```
{% for other in others %}
 {{other.id}}
{% endfor %}
```

The above method always shows the error as follow:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Notice: Array to string conversion").

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: That error occurs when you try to convert an array into a string check wheater you print your output is not an array if this then you have convert this into a string first.

Comment: how can i do it?

Comment: by debugging you variable you can check that it is an array or string. or you can share your complete code for more reference.

Comment: Try `{{ dump(other) }}`.

Comment: please you can share your complete twig file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this.

```
{% for other in others %}
    {% for o in other %}
        {{o.id}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

or

```
{% for other in others %}
    {{other[0].id}}
{% endfor %}
```